# Angular router-outlet name not work with lazy loading

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-routing, angular6, angular-router

I'm trying to replicate the lazy load using secondary routes, but these do not work, however

the project link is this.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gpxnaf

When I want to enter a personal section or user section, the route changes but it does not show anything, I use a proxycomponent, because I have already implemented this type of functionality in another private project, however now I can not make it work, fixing the example of the editor It's the same as I have in another private repository.

I do not know what I am failing, I would appreciate it if you can give me another point of view about my failure.
PD:Only the bottom buttons work.

> when I press the button the route is redirected correctly, the moduloe
>   UserModule and PersonalModule also loads but does not show me
>   anything.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The first thing we need to know, if we work with Lazy Loading Feature Modules, we don't need to specify component in our first routing file loaded with angular application because it's lazy and if I invoke an event this component was loaded. So we need to delete this line

```
component: ProxyComponent,
```

And now, we need to go see the routing file of Personal Module, here we have a lot of problems. So the routing in angular is a constant not a class

```
export class PersonalRoutingModule { }
```

And here we need to make a relationship between this file and our Personal Module with this code

```
export const PersonalRoutingModule: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

And we can't find a decorator of @NgModule in this file. We need to remove all those lines

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  declarations: [
    ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
```

Comment: hello I understand your suggestions, but my problem is not only with lazy, but using a secondary path along with lazy

Comment: I use the proxyComponent, it was a suggestion that I found in a github issue, that I worked in another repository with similar functionality, however when I pass it to stackblitz it does not work for me, and I do not think it's because of the angular version because in both I use 6.x

Comment: There is not much information about this feature, more than some trials and errors in github issues

Comment: hi, if you can specify exactly your problem because i see a lot of things here, like your proxyComponent is defiend in code not imported from remote `import {ProxyComponent, StateController} from 'panel';`. you need to see this documentation [component-utils](http://mixpanel.github.io/panel/module-component-utils.html)

Comment: My problem is the same one that is reported here.
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10981#issuecomment-398376712

In the example I put in I was trying several things.